# Different file name in URL and display original in Ms-office Webdav

Tags: .net, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I am creating a demo for my client using Webdav. But my problem is that I dont have unique name of document. So , i am using unique id of Document in Url in place of document name.

Now, problem is microsoft word is displaying the name in the url, I want to display original name instead.

How i can display original name in office but use a uniqueid in Url

Exapmle URL:ms-word:ofe|u|http://localhost:57701/_dav/Test/48cbf1a6-bdb1-4dcd-ba6d-ad74b7af5e6e.docx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want is to change your URL structure - if you serve the document from http://url/GUID/title.docx, Word will display the document name as title.docx.

You could even accomplish this with a URL rewrite rule.